# What are the free Image processing tools available to manipulate image regions and entire pixels?

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation, image-processing, image-viewers

I am working on an image task where I have to manipulate the regions and pixels in images. I need the tool to do 3 major task:

1. Draw a rectangle box on the image
2. Pick any pixel colour from the image and set all the pixels of the above Bounding Box to that specific colour.

I have images in `jpg` format and a maximum size are `1000x1000`.

I tried `pinta` but it crashes just after loading an image. `Xpaint` does not have that functionality.

Could someone please help. I think `paint` in Windows used to have such functionality.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a bit clunky, but you can do this with GIMP. Zoom way in, use the color picker to grab your pixel, rectangle select the area, then use bucket fill set to "Fill whole selection" to replace the contents of the rectangle.